# How to copy one branch to another regardless changes?

Tags: git, branch

I'm relatively new to Git; I usually use SVN.
We have several branches. Because I have not used my branch for a while, the master branch is far ahead of my branch. How can I copy master branch to my branch regardless my changes (both locally and remotely)?

Comment: can you give us an update on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose you want to **remove** all changes to your local branch and start again from master:

**THE FAST METHOD**

```
git checkout <your-branch>
git reset --hard master
git push -f origin <your-branch> #WARNING DANGEROUS COMMAND!!!!
```

**THE LONG METHOD BUT MAYBE EASIER TO UNDERSTAND**

go to master branch

```
git checkout master
```

now delete your branch, including **all your work on that branch!**

```
git branch -D <your-branch>
```

now recreate the branch on master, since you are still on master, you can just do:

```
git checkout -b <your-branch>
```

now push this to remote. You need to **force** pushing to remote, which is **dangerous** since you are changing your history on the remote (agreed, only for your-branch now)

```
git push -f origin <your-branch>
```

Comment: Recommending a force push? Really?

Comment: There is no way around this afaik... if you read his question... he asks to change "locally and on remote"... I know this is dangerous...

Comment: @Jubobs I made the command a little safer... what do you think?

Comment: What's wrong with merging master into the branch, or (under the assumption that this wouldn't involve any rewriting of public history) rebasing the branch to master?

Comment: he says "regardless my changes", so I understand he doesn't need his changes anymore...

Comment: Indeed don't need my changes anymore

Comment: OK and did you try my solution then?

Comment: Sorry guys I didn't try))) I've just killed my branch and made new one)))