# Git: overwriting code of one branch to another

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I have 2 branches A and B.  Both have diverged from master with lots of different commits, and the master has moved ahead.

What i want to do is replace all changes of B with A.
i.e., B should have exactly the same code as A.

I tried using rebase/merge. Even -Xtheirs while rebasing B, but always running into loads of conflicts.

i tried

```
git checkout B
git reset --hard A
```

as given in [How to copy one branch to another regardless changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34925739/how-to-copy-one-branch-to-another-regardless-changes) but this gave this-

```
Your branch and 'origin/B' have diverged,
and have 6603 and 1823 different commits each, respectively.
```

Is there a way i can get the code/commits of A copied to B, with no conflicts? Please help.

Comment: `git checkout A && git pull --rebase && git push -f origin B` (this **overwrites** B with A)

Comment: if you want to copy commits only, `git cherry-pick` is an option

Comment: git pull --rebase && git push -f origin B  -> Wont this bring all changes of B into A?

Comment: @ghostCoder do you want to replace the history of `B` with the history of `A` or do you just want to make one new commit on `B` that changes your complete codebase to the state that is present on `A`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're really trying to discard all your changes from B, which seems like a waste, then you can force update the branch pointer.

```
git branch -f A B
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout A -B B
```

Checkout the working tree of `A`, while giving it the branch name `B`.  (Since `B` already exists, `-B` (big B) is required to override.)

This is effectively the same as this:

```
# Checkout the branch 'A' and make the working tree reflect this
git checkout A

# Create/override a branch 'B' at this current position
git checkout -B B
```

The end result is that the branches (which are practically just *pointers*) 'A' and 'B' point the the exact same commit.

**N.B.** The end result of this is pretty much the same as what you had with `git checkout B && git reset --hard A`.

Now, since you seem to be concerned with the *`origin/B` has diversed* message, there're two things you can do at this point:

1. You can update `origin/B` to reflect your new `B` by ***force*** pushing:  (This is provided you aren't worried that commits that were originally in `origin/B` will cease to exist.)

   ```
   push origin B --force
   ```
2. For some reason, you're unable to force push (Fast-forward only server?)  Or you want to preserve the commit history that was under `B`--just not their changes.  In this case, it's a little more involved:  (This use case is quite rare so I'm not entirely certain this is what you're after):

   ```
   git checkout A --detach
   git merge -s ours B
   git checkout -B B
   ```

   This makes a merging commit that proceeds `A`, that merges `B` into `A` without actually changing any files.  This new `B` can be pushed normally as it's not a divergence from `origin/B`.

Comment: but i want both A and B to exist separately. just want to copy all the code/commits from A to B and override everything in B

Comment: @ghostCoder They will exist separately.  The two *branches* will have exactly the same "commits history" and code.

Answer (score 0):

Your command to reset your local branch `B` to `A` was all right.
The message you get just informs you that your local branch `B` is different from the remote branch `B`.
If this is really what you want to do, just now do a force push of `B` to `origin/B` with `git push -f origin B` if the remote allows force-pushes.
But be aware that you are rewriting published history and you will upset any other developers that based work on `B` as they have to recover from this manually by rebases of their work.