# Git Merge: Is it better to delete parts of a branch and merge, or to force merge and overwrite?

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I have done some looking around for an answer to my question, but my case seems to differ from the others that I have seen. The closest I have seen is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38202717/git-overwriting-code-of-one-branch-to-another).

#### Background

The repository that I have been working on has the common *develop* branch, but it also has a couple of branches that I haven't seen used in other repositories. We call these *scratchpad* branches, and we use them so our group members can pull others code to learn from it, as this is a class term project.

However, the idea is the *scratchpad* branches are **never** merged back into any other branch. They exist solely for experiment and early design. In my case, I have done work on my *scratchpad* branch to learn the proper way of implementing something, and then checked out a *feature* branch and properly implemented the code, with documentation. I am now at the point that I want to merge the *develop* branch with my *scratchpad* branch, in such a way as to use the *develop* code **instead** of any merge or combination of it and my *scratchpad* code.

#### The Actual Question

Say 3 branches exist: **develop**, **scratchpad**, and **feature**

- *scratchpad* and *feature* are both made by branching off of *develop*
- I checkout *scratchpad* and implement 2 files: *file1**, and *file2**
  Note: these are very bad implementations, as the goal is to figure out how
  to make it work
- I now checkout *feature* (which does not have either of the files created
  yet), and create and implement *file1* in a completely different way
  Note: I have not implemented *file2**, as it is still being tested and has
  nothing to do with *file1*
- I merge *feature* back into *develop*, so *file1* exists along the develop
  branch
- I now want to merge *develop* into *scratchpad*, and have it completely
  overwrite *scratchpad/file1* with *develop/file1*
  Note: I don't want to delete the branch because *file2* still exists there.
  I just want to overwrite same-named files with what is in develop.

How do I accomplish this? Do I delete the files in *scratchpad* and merge? Will that work? Do I do some sort of overwrite?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing should work. If you try to merge *develop* into *scratchpad* when they both have different versions of *file1*, you're almost certainly going to see merge conflicts. To avoid that, delete the file from *scratchpad* and commit that change before merging. Then that branch will not have a copy of *file1*, so there should be no conflicts when you merge the good version of that file in from *develop*.

After you merge, your commit log of the *scratchpad* branch should show *file1* being created, deleted, then created again with the new copy merged from the main branch.

Comment: Okay perfect! Thanks! I was unsure if the deletion would cause issues because it took place after (in time) than the creation on the other branch. Thanks for confirming this!